# Touch screen only works when charging

Tags: hardware, touchscreen, xiaomi, touch, redmi

My Xiaomi Redmi 3s's old screen was broken so I imported a new **LCD+Touch-screen with frame** from china. After fixing the new LCD, the touch screen(LCD is working perfectly) is not working but the surprising thing is the touch screen of the new LCD is working only when the phone is connected to a charger! When I unplug the charger the touch screen stops working.
any Idea why its happening? hope someone could help me.

Comment: You've most likely got a capacitive [touchscreen](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchscreen). It could be that the cable is not properly seated, damaged, or defective, or another part could've been damaged when your old screen was broken. Try re-seating the cable and make sure it's well connected. A voltage tester may be able to tell if the screen itself is defective, but I've never used that stuff so I'm not 100% sure it would be safe and if you want to go that route please wait for someone more knowledgeable to say if it would be okay.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried reconnecting the flex cable 3 or 4 times to make sure the cable is attached perfectly to the motherboard. Still the touch screen only works when the mobile is on charger!

Comment: No problem; I'm sorry it wasn't more helpful. There was (is?) apparently an issue with the [Galaxy S6](https://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s6-edge/636802-why-does-my-s6-edge-only-work-when-charging.html#post_4966854) like this which could be fixed by clearing the system cache. This should be perfectly safe to do, and may also make your device run better in the process...provided it fixes the touchscreen issue, lol. If that fails try editing to include your device, OS version, and some other info (but not MSN/ESN/MEID which are personal AFAIK; only hardware & software versions).

Comment: I will try clearing the cache. also will update the query with device details. thank you

Comment: I have done factory reset when connected to the charger(touch screen works when charger is connected), do I need to do a seperate cache cleaning? The touch screen still not working without the charger!

Comment: Sorry, I should've specified better -- they seem to mean to use "wipe cache partition" in recovery mode. There are different ways to get into recovery mode, but volume up and/or down + power is often it. Once in recovery mode unless you've got a touch-based recovery, usually with a custom recovery like TWRP, volume keys should become up/down & power select/enter. So, highlight an option with the volume keys and then press power to select it. You also often need to give confirmation or deny an action by selecting yes or no.

Comment: Tried wiping the cache partition but nothing helped! Touch screen only works when phone connected to a power source. :(

Comment: @l3l_aze Changed the touchscreen and now everything working fine. But its still unknown why the old touchscreen worked only when phone is connected to a charger! thanks for you help.